# CSS: Google maps tilt view?

Tags: css, google-maps

I'm trying to use CSS to change the angle of the google maps container so it's in tilt view mode.

The issue that I have is that the map view is tilt but the top of the page is empty even though the map container element's width is set to 100%.

This is a working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Rsp22/3332/)

And this is the CSS code:

```
#map-canvas {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     position:absolute;
     -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(40, 1, 0, 40deg)!important;
     -moz-transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(40, 1, 0, 40deg)!important;
     -o-transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(40, 1, 0, 40deg)!important;
     transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(40, 1, 0, 40deg)!important;
 }
```

Could someone please let me know if there is a way to get around this issue so the map is in tilt view but covers the entire page?

Note, Google maps support tilt view only for HYBRID and Satellite view and NOT the ROADMAP view which is what I am using.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work  on the dimension in px and not in %  see and the position of the map http://jsfiddle.net/apqpw08u/

eg :

```
#map-canvas {
 height: 1000px;
 width: 2000px;
 position:absolute;
 left: -500px;
 top: -500px;
 -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(40, 1, 0, 40deg)!important;
 -moz-transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(40, 1, 0, 40deg)!important;
 -o-transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(40, 1, 0, 40deg)!important;
 transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(40, 1, 0, 40deg)!important;
}
```

or in %  http://jsfiddle.net/apqpw08u/3/

```
#map-canvas {
 height: 200%;
 width: 200%;
 position:absolute;
 left: -50%;
 top: -50%;
 -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(40, 1, 0, 40deg)!important;
 -moz-transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(40, 1, 0, 40deg)!important;
 -o-transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(40, 1, 0, 40deg)!important;
 transform: perspective(1000px) rotate3d(40, 1, 0, 40deg)!important;
}
```

Comment: I need the width and height to be in %. I cannot give a px width and height to the map container because the center of the map will be lost in small screens (demonstrated in your fiddle too).